# How do I group into different dates based on change in another column values in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 'DATE': ['1/1/2015','1/2/2015', '1/3/2015','1/4/2015','1/5/2015','1/6/2015','1/7/2015','1/8/2015',
  '1/9/2016','1/2/2015','1/3/2015','1/4/2015','1/5/2015','1/6/2015','1/7/2015'],
 'CD': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','A','A','C','A','A','A','A','A','A']})
```

[image]

What I would like to do is group by ID and CD and get the start and stop change for each change. I tried using groupby and agg function but it will group all A together even though they needs to be separated since there is B in between 2 A.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','CD'])
df1 = df1.agg(
    Start_Date = ('Date',np.min),
    End_Date=('Date', np.min)
).reset_index()
```

What I get is :

[image]

I was hoping if some one could help me get the result I need. What I am looking for is :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make `grouper` for grouping

```
grouper = df['CD'].ne(df['CD'].shift(1)).cumsum()
```

`grouper`:

```
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     3
7     3
8     4
9     5
10    5
11    5
12    5
13    5
14    5
Name: CD, dtype: int32
```

then use groupby with `grouper`

```
df.groupby(['ID', grouper, 'CD'])['DATE'].agg([min, max]).droplevel(1)
```

output:

```
        min         max
ID  CD      
1   A   1/1/2015    1/4/2015
    B   1/5/2015    1/6/2015
    A   1/7/2015    1/8/2015
    C   1/9/2016    1/9/2016
2   A   1/2/2015    1/7/2015
```

change column name and use reset_index and so on..for your desired output

```
(df.groupby(['ID', grouper, 'CD'])['DATE'].agg([min, max]).droplevel(1)
 .set_axis(['Start_Date', 'End_Date'], axis=1)
 .reset_index()
 .assign(CD=lambda x: x.pop('CD')))
```

result

```
    ID  Start_Date  End_Date    CD
0   1   1/1/2015    1/4/2015    A
1   1   1/5/2015    1/6/2015    B
2   1   1/7/2015    1/8/2015    A
3   1   1/9/2016    1/9/2016    C
4   2   1/2/2015    1/7/2015    A
```